# Does the Rune Knight choose the new target for Cloud Rune or does the original target choose the new target?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, targeting, unearthed-arcana, rune-knight

Quoting from the [Rune Knight](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-RuneSwarmRevived.pdf)'s Skye (Cloud Rune)

> In addition, when you or a creature you can see within 30 feet of you is hit by an attack roll, you can use your reaction to invoke the rune and cause that attack to target a different creature within 30 feet of you (other than the attacker), using the same roll. This magic can transfer the attack regardless of the attack’s range. Once you invoke the rune, you can’t do so again until you finish a short or long rest.

Does that mean the Rune Knight chooses the new target for the attack?

Answer (score 6):

### The updated feature in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything is clear.

The feature as presented in TCoE is different:

> [...] you can use your reaction to invoke the rune and choose a different creature within 30 feet of you [...]

This makes it very clear that the Rune Knight as carrier of the runes chooses the new target.

### The feature from UA was not entirely clear

The feature in the UA (which you cite) does not clearly state whether you or the original target choose the new target, neither does it say "randomly chosen", meaning that it should be chosen by someone. Unearthed Arcana are Playtest material which is not checked as thoroughly as the material in source books before publishing.

**Looking at the details it seems like you would choose**

- It is your magic effect which implies that you choose, *a priori*.
- Thematically, the part of the rune that you didn't cite talks about deceptiveness. This implies that other persons present might not even be fully aware of what's happening.
- The effect says "you [...] cause that attack to target a different creature”. If you cause the attack to hit someone else, it should be you who chooses. Especially since it can be anyone within range. It is not hitting a random bystander.
- Note also, that you hit someone within 30 feet of *you*, not the attacker or the original target.